# ComboBox property autocomple in Windows store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using a combobox control in a windows store app, and I need to have the autocomplete property with search, but I can't found it.
Any idea how can I use it??
Thnaks

Maria

Answer (score 3):

I have written my own AutoCompleteBox control, available at https://github.com/igorkulman/AutoCompleteBox

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built in, but have you checked open source? This was the first thing that showed up when I binged for it on google:

http://autocompleteboxwinrt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19567

Comment: nice find, but not finished and seems dead

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in AutoCompleteBox control for Windows Store app. 
You may consider a third party control such as:

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/auto-complete.aspx